# redirectmatch not picked up in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I try to redirect a ddos attacks. I use redirectmatch conditions, but somehow it is not working in my htacces. the code is

```
RedirectMatch 301 \d*\?_uw=\d* http://www.someurl.com
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^\d*\?_uw=\d* http://www.someurl.com [L,R=301]
```

None of above is working. I would like to match following urls where numbers are always changing **197831051715412?_uw=9351823359**

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _uw=\d*
RewriteRule ^\d*$ http://www.someurl.com/? [L,R=301]
```

With this other last line:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.someurl.com/? [L,R=301]
```

You don't test file name (if they also use letters) only `_uw=`

Comment: hi how to redirect to url without appending the string? now it appends the string to the new url. thank you

Comment: @user1031743: Use `RewriteRule ^\d*$ http://www.someurl.com/? [L,R=301]` to strip off any query string.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you. I add this change in my answer. And now that work without query string in the new url.